# Convergent series in Hilbert space

Tags: sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces

I am looking for a proof of the following theorem.

Consider a countable orthonormal set in Hilbert space
$H :\ \ u_1, u_2, ...$

$\sum_{j=1} ^{\infty} r_ju_j$ is convergent in $H \iff \sum_{j=1} ^{\infty} |r_j|^2$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$

If these series are convergent, then they are unconditionally convergent.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: Have you tried any direction of the implications?

Comment: What do you know about the norm of a sum of orthogonal vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If LHS converges to $u\in H$, what is $||u||$?

If RHS converges, define $v_n= \sum_{j=1}^n r_ju_j$.  Prove that $\{||v_n||\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy's. From where does it follow that $\lim_{n\to\infty} v_n$ exists?